# TTS reads B after number as "bytes"

Tags: java, android, audio, text-to-speech

I have a problem: When I have a string, for Example "1 2 B", the TTS-Engine reads it out as "one two bytes". What I need it to read out only the letter, not the possible meaning behind it. Can I disable this formatting somehow? Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
I'm using the Samsung TTS Engine.

Comment: I just tested it. It doesn't say "one two bytes". It says "one two b".

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it's the Samsung TTS

Comment: For single letters, map them to their phonetic sounds. The behaviour will differ between engines.